# How to display even positions in data oaf a column in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

column Name: employee_number
values: 256749,358976,583546

want ouput as 579,596,856

how can i do this? irrespective of length or datatype?

Comment: Is your source data that you are showing 3 rows of data or a single row? What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: Employee_number Output should be
256749 579
358976 596
583546 856       3 rows and datatype we can change it with to_varchar or something

Comment: i need to display only even number positions irrespective of length in each row

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
WITH src AS (    
    SELECT *
      FROM VALUES (256749),(358976),(583546) AS t(employee_number)
)
SELECT src.employee_number, LISTAGG(s.VALUE, '') AS ouput
  FROM src,
  TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(REGEXP_REPLACE(employee_number::string, '.', ',\\0', 2), ',')) AS s
 WHERE s.INDEX % 2 = 0
 GROUP BY src.employee_number, s.SEQ;
```

Result:

```
+------------------+--------+
| EMPLOYEE_NUMBER  | OUTPUT |
+------------------+--------+
|           358976 |    596 |
|           256749 |    579 |
|           583546 |    856 |
+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: wow! its awesome... but i cant give the values if I am having millions of records right?

Comment: Substitute your table in place of the sample SRC table. The WITH clause of SELECT VALUES is just to have sample data.